# Beyond just Morale what qualities\acheivements obtained in inFamous have effects in inFamous 2 and what are those effects?

Tags: infamous-2

I know about Morale, and JohnoBoy has mentioned that it also records the blast shards youve collected, but what else is taken into account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completing the game as good or evil grants you the option to start at hero level 1 or evil level 1, respectively. Regardless, there's a 1000xp bonus for any game completion, good or bad.

There is a an energy core bonus for collecting 25% of the shards, another energy core for collecting 50%.

Also, the game will sometime reference karma decisions made in the previous game, for example, when collecting a certain dead drop in Infamous 2 I heard someone describe my karma choice in the doctors rooftop rescue mission in Infamous 1.

Comment: I will 'check' once reasonably sure youve covered everything. Thanks :-)